# How do i get the string after an element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several forms on my page.  Each form is named according to the ID in the database.

```
<form id="spam-X" method="post">
```

So on my page, if there are 3 comments, there are 3 forms.

```
<form id="spam-1" method="post">...</form>  <form id="spam-2" method="post">...</form>   <form id="spam-3" method="post">...</form>
```

Now I want to run a set of functions for based on what form is submitted.  So I have my submit function in jquery...

```
$("form#[id^='spam']").submit(function() {
```

Now the problem is, I want to get the contents within this specific form that was clicked, so I'm assuming I will need the trailing ID (spam-1, spam-2, spam-3).... How do I get that value?

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$("form#[id^='spam']").submit(function() {  
   var formThatWasSubmitted = this;
}
```

The to get the value of a particular input in that form:

```
var email = this.email.value;
```

Comment: What's the jQuery wrapper for? The `this` value alone is a reference to the form...

Comment: I was under the impression `this` would not be a jQuery extended object when called directly from the submit function. Therefore to use `find()` on it it needs to be extended with `$()`

Comment: Why use `.find()`?  Just use `this.email.value`

Comment: The element is avaiable directly as a property of the form, so *this.email* is the control and *this.email.value* is its value. That saves creation of a jQuery object and two method calls and replaced it with two property lookups (so it will run about 10,000 times faster, maybe more).

Comment: All totally valid points, I've updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to refer to the form by it's specific ID, because the function you bind to the submit handler will be called with 'this' being the DOM element of the form. You can get the text content of the form using the text() function:

```
$("form#[id^='spam']").submit(function() {
     // 'this' is the dom element that is being submitted
     var text = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$(this).attr('id')` inside the `submit` handler.

Comment: Well, he asked for the id, but I thought that an explanation using `$(this)` might hint him that `this` is not the jq object in that context (which is far more useful for whatever he wants to do with the form).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $(this) inside the function to get access to the form that was activated by the click.

Then using something like `$(this).find("SELECTOR").val()` to narrow down to the field that you need the information from. Where you'd need to substitute *SELECTOR* with the name or class selector for your field inside that form.